# getting textBlock from list view dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, textblock

I have a ListView which contain 2 textBlocks as a listview Item

I want to color the textBlocks dynamically

how can I get do the textblock? 
will appreciate an example.

Thanks you for your support

attaching My XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="LV" ItemsSource= "{Binding  Lggv}" SelectionChanged="dataGridData_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel >
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" Text="{Binding Info }" AllowDrop="True"   FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2" >
                                    <TextBlock.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">                                              
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFCEE6C6" Offset="0.008"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9ECF8C" Offset="0.987"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </TextBlock.Background>

                                </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Grid x:Name="GridData" >
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC5DDFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA8C8F7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}" ></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComPort}"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" ></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>    
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>                                

            </ListView>
```

Comment: i would use a ValueConverter to change the value of a binding to a brush, then the binding will do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a IValueConverter

as this allows you to keep your view and viewModel seperate, though if you don't care about that @sasanaf answer is perfertly correct

here is an example of a simple Brush based converter

```
public class PriorityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush HighBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush LowBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush MediumBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush DefaultBrush { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var priority = value as Priority?;
        if (priority.HasValue)
        {
            switch (priority.Value)
            {
                case Priority.High:
                    return HighBrush;
                case Priority.Medium:
                    return MediumBrush;
                case Priority.Low:
                    return LowBrush;
                default:
                    return DefaultBrush;
            }
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidCastException($"{value} is not a Priority");
    }
```

You would then add the converter as a resource to your App,

```
<local:PriorityConverter x:Key="PriorityConverter" >
    <local:PriorityConverter.DefaultBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlColorKey}}"/>
    </local:PriorityConverter.DefaultBrush>
    <local:PriorityConverter.HighBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </local:PriorityConverter.HighBrush>
    <local:PriorityConverter.MediumBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
    </local:PriorityConverter.MediumBrush>
    <local:PriorityConverter.LowBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
    </local:PriorityConverter.LowBrush>
</local:PriorityConverter>
```

and finally use it on your binding

```
<TextBlock Background="{Binding Priority, Converter={StaticResource PriorityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Good Approach 1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a MVVM approach, i would set the colors in the ViewModel and bind them to the properties.

Edit: 
Textblock like this:

```
                               <TextBlock DataContext="ViewModel"
                                       Background="{Binding SpecificColor}">
                               </TextBlock>
```

And in ViewModel you can specifiy at initialization or at any specific event wich color you would like.
For Example :

```
private Brush m_SpecificColor;
    public Brush SpecificColor
    {
        get { return m_SpecificColor; }
        set
        {
            m_SpecificColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SpecificColor");
        }
    }
    private void SetColor()
    {
        SpecificColor = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Green");
    }
```

Comment: Brushes are view elements having them in the View Model isn't a good idea

Comment: Well can you tell me where the disadvantage of this approach is? 
The alternative would be a IValueConverter for the Colors, like depending the Data you have, the color you get.

Comment: if your using the converter then no issues at all, but say you want to change the theme and have a different colour or if you are using the same VM in 2 different views, and don't want to be the same colours in both places. if the brush is in your VM it can't be changed, but using a converter you just change the resources from the view

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change the colour dynamically based on some property of the object (the class with the "Info", "DateTime", "ComPort" and "Data" properties) in your Lggv source collection.

You could then use a style with a DataTrigger that binds to a property of this class, i.e. the the type `T` (again this is the one with the "Info", "DateTime", "ComPort" and "Data" properties) of the `IEnumerable<T>` (Lggv) source collection that you bind to:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" Text="{Binding Info}" AllowDrop="True"   FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- this is the default background-->
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFCEE6C6" Offset="0.008"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9ECF8C" Offset="0.987"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- This trigger changes the background to green when the "Info" property of your data object returns "Some info..." -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Info}" Value="Some info...">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>Green</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IValueConverter to convert property to background color. Below is an example.

```
class BackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush myLinearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        if (value != null )
        {
            string strValue = value.ToString();


            myLinearGradientBrush.StartPoint = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0);
            myLinearGradientBrush.EndPoint = new System.Windows.Point(1, 1);

            switch (strValue)
            {
                case "Match1":
                    myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
                    myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.25));
                    break;
                case "Match2":
                    myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Blue , 0.0));
                    myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.BlueViolet, 0.25));
                    break;
                default:
                    myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Green , 0.0));
                    myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.GreenYellow, 0.25));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return myLinearGradientBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Declare value convert in resource as below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BackgroundColorConverter"/>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Below is the coder of Xaml.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" Text="{Binding Info }" Background="{Binding Path=property, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundColorConverter}}" AllowDrop="True"   FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

another approach if you want to use resource. You can define color in windows or user control resource. After this you will have to use IMultiValueConverter. Pass you property and windows or user control to MultiValueConverter. You need to use relative source to get windows or usercontrol in binding. Then you can return the resource as per the matching condition.

Comment: you don't need to use IMultiValueConverter to use resources, just set them as properties

Comment: As per the question, If he want to use LinearGradientBrush  from resource   , He will have multiple resources and need to set that with property according to the property value. So, if there is a single resource which you want then you can user to set property otherwise you need to multivalue converter to get correct resource as per the value.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd do this with a DataTrigger:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFCEE6C6" Offset="0.008"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF9ECF8C" Offset="0.987"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="YourPropertyValue">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.008"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.987"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You don't then have to have a class defined to do what is a relatively simple task.